Can I use the convergence test results of ecutwfc, ecutrho, and k points obtained from a 2x2 graphene supercell for a larger graphene supercell?
Recently, I conducted convergence tests (ecutwfc, ecutrho, and k points) for a 2x2 graphene supercell, yielding results of 120 Ry, 300 Ry, and 10x10x1 respectively. (Here, we considered convergence accuracy up to 4 decimal points.) Now, I want to use an 8x8 graphene supercell. Is it possible to use the ecutwfc, ecutrho, and k points parameters obtained from the 2x2 supercell in the 8x8 supercell?.

I am kind of disturbed that your k point convergence plot is not monotonic. Your ecutrho is also chosen to be absurdly large. Can you zoom in the plot for 200 to 300 Ry? Isn't the default ecutrho = 4x ecutwfc?

As far as I remember, the larger is the supercell size the less is the k-points number to achieve the convergence. So, when you increase your cell you don’t need to increase the number of k-points. However, I would say from your plot that 10x10x1 is not enough for convergence of 2x2 cell, because the curve is still fluctuating.
The cutoff parameters (ecutwfc, ecutrho) are not affected much by the cell size, so you can leave them the same as in 2x2.

@naturallyInconsistent Of course, you are right that it is the default, but I thought it would be better if I conducted a convergence test. I will try to attach a zoomed image for you.

@Victor Thank you. Although it's fluctuating, if you closely look, you can see it has converged to four decimal places. If that's the case, is it fine to use 10x10x1 for an 8x8 cell?

@naturallyInconsistent Here are the ecutrho values from 200 to 300 Ry
200 -91.11162704
210 -91.11163285
220 -91.11163337
230 -91.11163351
240 -91.11163499
250 -91.11160833
260 -91.11161155
270 -91.11156688
280 -91.11156767
290 -91.11158858
300 -91.11158777

I worry that your convergence testing itself is inconsistent. You should be letting ecutrho = 4ecutwfc, i.e. the default, and testing ecutwfc, so that both are converged together. Then you leave ecutwfc = 120Ry and see if ecutrho being changed would change much. The default there should be fine. Your k points convergence is very suspect.

Please provide the numbers in a code block rather than a screenshot.

@Ihavenofreetimeanymore, I have changed it to the number as you requested

Note, the reason to use ecutrho = 4 x ecutwfc is that the density requires wave-vectors up 4 x ecutwfc to correctly reproduce the density. Decreasing ecutrho introduces truncation errors and increasing it has no affect on the accuracy (in-princple): see here https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Wrap-around_errors . For PAW, I think the density in the PAW sphere is represented differently which is why quantum espresso suggests to check convergence wrt to ecutrho ONLY if using PAW datasets. Are you using pseudopotentials of PAW?

Also see the very comprehensive answer here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/10074/1258

Please provide the numbers in text.
